# Lambda and Foreach

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method:

```
public Wrapper(Action<string> codeBlock)
{
   //Code code code

        Parallel.ForEach<Computer>(Computers, computer =>
        {
                //CODE CODE 
               codeblock();

               //More code

        );
    //more code

 }
```

I use it to put a code block inside a wrapper that make important things to my app.

I invoke it using something like

```
Wrapper((s) => {

//My Code block
//code
//More code

});
```

I want to use the object computer of the collection Computers, created in the foreach of the wrapper, in my code block.
So if I made something like this:

```
Wrapper((s) => {

//My Code block
 AFunction(computer);
//More code

});
```

It obviouslly fails because "computer" does not exists in the contexts where I invoke the wrapper, only exists inside the foreach of the wrapper.

So how could I accomplish this? Maybe I have an error design?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public Wrapper(Action<Computer> codeBlock)` then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
public Wrapper(Action<Computer> codeBlock)
{
    //...
    Parallel.ForEach<Computer>(Computers, computer =>
    {
           //...
           codeblock(computer);
           //...
    );
}
```

instead.

```
Wrapper((s) => {    // s is of type Computer here now
    //...
    AFunction(s);
    //...
});
```

Of course , you may use `Action<T1,T2>` (i.e. relevant delegate with the necessary number of parameters) if you need both `Computer` and `string` within your code block. Lambda expression would be changed accordingly: `(s, comp) => { /*...*/ }`